# Can anyone help me to query from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to access the flights array as in the image and get records 10 by 10. I tried different ways by mapping the flights array.
Here is what i tried in postman

```
 PUT http://12.234.17.134:9200/index-flights
    {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "flights": {
            "type": "nested" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
    GET http://12.234.17.134:9200/index-flights/_search
    { 
    "query": {
        "match": {
          "result.id": "2erfc096-3db0-4817-88fc-69db286e95b8"
        },
        "query": {
       "nested": {
          "path": "flights"
       }
        }
      }
     }
```

Image of the structure of my data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K378p.png

Comment: Please elaborate what is your use-case. Are you trying to find a query which returns all the documents with `result.id` as what you've mentioned in your question and in response you only want to see `flights` data and not the entire document?

Comment: Thanks.Yes exactly not the whole document. The whole document needs to be selected from the "result.id" (underlined) and then I need to access the "flights" array 10 by 10 records (paging) only. I need to access the flights[] from API calls from angular. New image is attached (https://i.imgur.com/uG0kr6O.png) and which shows the document structure the below query works but returns the whole document with the flights array. https://i.imgur.com/ynYPy1g.png

Comment: Further 1st  API call I need to access first 1-10 of the flights[] and then 2nd call 11-20 and so on, each time I send the index and the  result.id to select the document uniquely and then get 10 by 10 from array.

Answer (score 2):

Go with an `_id` query -- no need for the nested one (which if malformed anyways):

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "2erfc096-3db0-4817-88fc-69db286e95b8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        "2erfc096-3db0-4817-88fc-69db286e95b8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Tip: never share public cluster IPs in online forums.*

Comment: Thanks.  The whole document is selected from the "result.id" (underlined). I want to access the "flights" array 10 by 10 records (paging) from the document. I need to access the flights[] from API calls from angular. New image is attached and which shows the whole document structure.  https://i.imgur.com/uG0kr6O.png

Comment: I can access the document by 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "result.id": "85dc984c-7159-4b64-bb28-a551a0132ad2"
    }
  }
} 
Please tell me the way to access the flights array only.

Comment: If you want to return only the flights array, use `"_source": "result.flights"` on the top level of your query request. As for `result.id`, you may wanna use `term` instead of `match` -- but that depends on your mapping which you didn't share.

Comment: Thanks.but again the whole document with the flight array returns as below. https://i.imgur.com/CFsDjjE.png

Comment: Can you paste the responses instead of screenshotting them?

Comment: its too long to show the whole element , since an array element has 713 lines of code.(complex object structure).   "_source": {
          "result": {
            "flights": [
              {
                "id": "668bd5b9-d61e-46da-812e-242a869bc033",
                "punitId": 0,
                "finalSellingPrice": {
                  "totalPrice": 1689.0,
                  "totalTax": 246.0,
                  "totalInsurance": 0.0,
                  "creditCardCommision": 0.0,
                  "agentOwnMarkeup": 0.0,
                  "totalMarkup": 30.0,

Comment: I see. Try searching `result.id.keyword` instead.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work   https://i.imgur.com/EzSZAZ3.png

Comment: What's your mapping? `GET index-name/_mapping`

Comment: no mappings. do i need to have a mapping to get this done ?

Comment: Mappings are auto-generated or user-defined. Either way, one always exists. I need to see it in order to help you.

Comment: do you mean the request parameters ?  http://xx.xx.xx.xx/flightresults/_search  . our index is flightresults. so under the flightresults a single document can be fetched by result.id and i need to get  the flights array of a single document 10 by 10 records. hope this answers your question.